# Best method to convert a vim <expr> value to neovim in lua

Tags: vim, lua, neovim

I am working to convert from Vim to NeoVim and am trying to transfer commands from my init.vim and .`vimrc` files to my lua files.  I had a command in my `.vimrc` file that would recognize the term r80= meant that the value of r80= should be replaced with 80 = characters.  The command in my `.vimrc` file was

```
iab <expr> r80= repeat('=', 80)
```

I have the following structure for my `nvim` file in `.config`

```
nvim
├── after
│   └── plugin
│       ├── colors.lua
│       ├── fugitive.lua
│       ├── harpoon.lua
│       ├── lsp.lua
│       ├── telescope.lua
│       ├── treesitter.lua
│       └── undotree.lua
├── init.lua
├── lua
│   └── core
│       ├── init.lua
│       ├── packer.lua
│       ├── remap.lua
│       └── set.lua
└── plugin
    └── packer_compiled.lua
```

Within the `nvim/core/set.lua` file I have tried the following

```
vim.cmd("iab <expr> r80= repeat('=', 80)")
```

However this does not appear to work.  How can I embed this functionality into Neovim with lua files?